# Is there a setCurrency function for a discord bot using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

As the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html) helps you with two functions, `currency.add()` and `currency.getBalance()`, there should be a `currency.setBalance()` function. Here is the code for the two functions:

```js
Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});
```

Could anybody help with making a `setBalance` function? I appreciate all help!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow so some formatting is incorrect

Comment: Do you mean help with making a `set` function, not a `getBalance` function since it already exists?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to make a setBalance() function, so I can set the balance for any user.

Comment: Sorry about the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted the `add()` function to set the amount instead of adding a certain amount:

```js
Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'setBalance', {
    value: async function setBalance(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance = Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});
```